# selecting all checkboxes in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to select all checkboxes of a specific name by checking a single checkbox on a page and trigger the subsequent events.

As I have it at the moment it doesnt seem to fire immediately, so upon the first checking of the 'select all' checkbox the checkboxes are not selected and then by unchecking the 'select all' check box all the checkboxes are checked.

Seems a bit upside down.

How can I improve the following code so that it works properly?

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name='chkAllBs']", function () {

if ($('input[name = chkBestSeller]').prop('checked') == false) {
    $('input[name=chkBestSeller]').attr("checked", "true");
    $('input[name=chkBestSeller]').trigger('click');
}
else {
    $('input[name=chkBestSeller]').attr("checked", "false");
    $('input[name=chkBestSeller]').trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be like

```
if ($('input[name = chkBestSeller]').prop('checked') == true) {

    $('input[name=chkBestSeller]').attr("checked", true);
} else {

    $('input[name=chkBestSeller]').attr("checked", false);
}
```

Or simply

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name='chkAllBs']", function () {
    $('input[name="chkBestSeller"]').prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name='chkAllBs']", function () {
    $('input[name=chkBestSeller]').prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name='chkAllBs']", function () {
    var c = this.checked;
    $('input[name = chkBestSeller]').prop('checked',c);
});
```